# How to lock "Regional and Language Options" in Win7

Tags: windows-7

I use an application (namely Kingsoft Spredsheets) which changes my regional settings (e.g. decimal separator ,) to English ones (decimal separator .).

It does so every time it is started or closed, no matter if I set in its "Options->General and save->Set decimal symbol to ," or not.

I know that I should report that to the software manufacturer, but it will take them some time to release a fixed version (if they fix it).

Is there any way to prevent this application from changing my regional settings? (I don't have group policy editor available in my Windows edition.)

Comment: Without the ability to change the group policy I know of now way of preventing the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lock

Those settings are stored in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` registry key. In order to lock it, you need change the Access Control List (ACL), and disable write access for everyone but the Administrators group and the system:

1. Create a new text file with this exact content:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International [1 8 17]
   ```

   Just as a reference, here are some valid numbers:

   ```
   1  - Administrators Full Access
   7  - World Full Access
   8  - World Read Access
   17 - System Full Access
   ```
2. Save it as `regini.txt`.
3. Open a command prompt, type the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   regini "X:\Path\to\regini.txt"
   ```

**Note** This will also prevent *you* from changing those values, unless you manually edit them by running `regedit` as administrator. Keep in mind the program might not work correctly if it can't write to the registry. In that case you could export the registry key content, and re-import everything back after closing the program, thus undoing the changes.

## Unlock

Reverting back requires similar steps: you just need to change the `regini.txt` file, like this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International [1 7 17]
```

Comment: Yes, it works great. The program seems to work OK (but I didn't test it thoroughly yet). I was thinking of taking ownership on that node by a different user but this is just elegant.

Comment: @NotAnAdmin By the way, you don't really need the Group Policy Editor to change a particular policy. In fact, you could simply edit/create the registry key which the policy refers to. Either way, even if you *did* have the policy editor, there aren't any policies suited to your needs AFAIK.